# Velocity from Acceleration

Tags: white-noise

In geological instrumentation, it is frequent to find the "integration of the acceleration" procedure, as the "empirical estimate" of the velocity, namely, the Particle Point Velocity (PPV).

Assuming:

- An electrical additive noise,
- A sampling time $d\tau$ over time, functions and integrals.

an accelerometer register can be simply modeled as:

$$a(t)=a_0(t)+e(t)\quad e(t)\sim\mathcal N(0,\sigma)$$

Thus the velocity estimate would be:

$$ v(t)=\int_0^ta_0(\tau)d\tau+\int_0^te(\tau)d\tau=v_0(t)+\int_0^te(\tau)d\tau$$

Where $a_0(t)$ and $v_0(t)$ are the real signals which we want.

For cancelling the "noisy" tendency in $v(t)$, a "baseline correction" procedure is naively stated as the "correct" procedure. Which is nothing more than fitting a customary function to the wiener process.

This is a "Dead Reckoning" process.

**Which should be the optimal way for estimating $v_0(t)$? from a mathematical point of view.**

PS: The estimate at the instant $t$, of a Wiener Process with conditional deviation $\sigma$, under a sampling time $d\tau$ is:

$$w(t)\sim\mathcal N\left(0,\sigma \sqrt\frac{t}{d\tau}\right)$$

Hence, if the resolution of the sensor is $\alpha$, after the time  $\alpha^2\frac{d\tau}{\sigma^2}$ the integrated noise will surpass the sensor resolution with "1-sigma" confidence, invalidating the procedure.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not fully clear on your set up. In the general case, even without noise, you cannot necessarily assume the integration constant is zero. So the model seems to imply a purely oscillatory motion? If the position amplitude bounded? (position = integral of velocity.) If so, then the errors cannot be completely uncorrelated, no?

Comment: Check the correction. It is still unclear for me how to state the problem. I dont know, which is the "correct" method for estimating $v_0$. All "experienced" people is proposing the integral method as valid. If you can help me would be great.

Comment: For the "baseline correction" approach, are there any validation studies using an independent measurement of velocity? I guess my feeling is that if this method of estimating velocity is found to be practically useful, then the noise is probably not truly uncorrelated.

Comment: The baseline correction since 20 years ago is to fitting a polynomial. for correcting the Wiener noise. It is much better to elliminate the Wiener with a smoother filter. But it has no teorethical base, just a look and feel base. For fitting the polynomials, the people impose conditions like "the floor doesnt end accelerating". Which is obvious, just to fit some orders, but useless at the end. Of course, no engineers talks about the Wiener process. That baseline correction has origin on supposing a "initial" and "final" movement. Which could be valid. But not on the general case.

Comment: But does the "white noise measurement error" have a strong theoretical and/or empirical base? (BTW is the context [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_ground_motion) kind of thing? In that article at least, "peak ground velocity" does not seem to be taken literally, but as a proxy.)

Comment: Normally the white noise in electrical systems is a fair good estimate model. Aplying a filter over the accelerogram is ok, because the filter cancels the noise. But the procedure on obtaining a velocity estimate is unclear for me. Should i filter after and/or before, under which filter power, or under which conditions?... Absolutely no idea.... Just gut estimate and look and feel reasoning.. lol....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44774/discussion-between-geomatt22-and-hypfco).